# updating and updated model events are ignored

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Why the `updating` and `updated` model events are ignored when `getDirty()` is empty?

If there are no changes for the model, doesn't mean I'm not updating its relationships.

**Update**

The following code:

```
public function updating(Eloquent $model)
{
    $history = new ContentHistory($model->getOriginal());
    $history->added_on = new DateTime;        
    $model->history()->save($history);
}
```

Is never triggered if `getDirty()` is empty. I have added `$touches = ['content']` to the `ContentHistory` model, but for no avail.

Comment: Maybe you have to touch the model from the related one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Touching Parent Timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps):

When you update any related model and if you want to update the parent's timestamp when the child model is updated then just use the `protected $touches = array('modelname');` property. For example, if you have a `Post` model and it has a child model as `Comment` and if you want to update the `Post` model (only `updated_at` timestamp field) then add a `$touches` property/array in the `Comment` model and add the name of the Parent model in that array like:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent {

    protected $touches = array('post');

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I would prefer not to be dependent on `$touches`, but this is good.

Comment: Sorry for missing this before, but actually this doesn't seem to work. Please see my update at the question.